# RunWithElevatedPrivileges -- with/without delegate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user, runwithelevatedprivileges

Here two methods below that uses `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`. I just want to know the difference between two?

Method 1:

```
public void Method1(SPUser user)
        {
            if (RequireImpersonation == true)
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { PerformRemoveFromVisitorsGroup(user); });
            else
                PerformRemoveFromVisitorsGroup(user);
        }
```

Mehtod 2:

```
public void Method2(SPUser user)
        {
            if (RequireImpersonation == true)
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => PerformRemoveFromVisitorsGroup(user));
            else
                PerformRemoveFromVisitorsGroup(user);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the code is compiled, there is no difference between these two. In this case - `delegate { }` is equal to `() => { }`. There are a couple of things, but they are not relevant in this case:

1. If you assign the lambda to a delegate type (such as Func or Action) you'll get an anonymous delegate. [1]
2. If you assign the lambda to an Expression type, you'll get an expression tree instead of a anonymous delegate. The expression tree can then be compiled to an anonymous delegate. [1]

[1] - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions